# How to remove overflow: hidden placed by bootstrap 5 modal?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, overflow

I am using bootstrap 5 for a react application. My problem is, every second time when I am opening a modal, there following style is placed on the body element: `style="overflow: hidden; padding-right: 17px;"` and also the class `modal-open`, which is preventing me to scroll outside the modal even after I am closing it. Is there any possibility to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate every bootstrap class in you scc or scss file. Just call that class and remove style that you do not want. In your case you can set

```
.modal{
   overflow: auto !important;
}
```